# How to do a load testing for a dynamic url?

Tags: jmeter, jmx, blazemeter

I am trying to do a load testing,but facing some issues.
The basic concept in the web app is that the users gives a request for which response links should be generated.(just like google search where we enter a request and click submit and on the next page we get response(website links ).

following are the steps

1. Initial page of the the browser has a text area where users enter the request in a text area and clicks on submit
2. The response links will be given in the next page. it takes at least 30 sec to pick the respective links .

The url in the second page is a dynamic url.

i have recorded the process using blazemter and obtained the jmx .
On using the jmx file in jmeter to test for 100 users,it is taking the same url(second page url) that was recorded by blazemeter
for all the 100 users hence we are getting the response  links on millisec for all the 100 users.

how can i ensure that for 100 users 100 dyanamic url will be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add as a child of the first request a [CSS/JQuery extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) that will extract a random link and use it in the following HTTP Request that simulates the click.

This extractor uses this syntax for extraction:

- https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

And you need to use 0 as number to ensure randomness.

Comment: Thank you  i was able to capture now:)

Answer (score 0):

If you export the recording in **SmartJMX** mode the relevant [Regular Expression Extractors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) Post-Processors will be added to your script in order to handle dynamic parameters (if any) so each JMeter thread (virtual user) will get its own dynamic URL.

I would recommend running your test with 2-3 users first and having [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener enabled so you could inspect request and response details and ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing prior to simulating large loads.

Check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this link,it was really helpful